# Problem in using underset in math mode

Tags: equations

I was writing an equation with the code below

```
\newcommand{\uint}[4]{      
       \ensuremath{\underset{#3}{\int_{\!{#1}}^{#2}{#4}}}
       }

\def \integrando {\rho_{\mathrm{\mu c}}\frac{\dd p^{3N} \dd q^{3N}} {h^{3N}}}
\begin{document}
     $$\uint{}{}{\mathrm{PhaseSpace}}{\integrando}=1$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to remove the space before "PhaseSpace" and aligh the \int with "PhaceSpace"?

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: How is `\other_expression` defined?

Comment: [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qngi2.png)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

 \newcommand{\uint}[4]{
       \ensuremath{\underset{#3}{\int_{\!{#1}}^{#2}{#4}}}
       }
 \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\def \integrando {\rho_{\mu \mathrm{canonico}}\frac{\dd p^{3N} \dd q^{3N}} {h^{3N}}}

     \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

     \[ \int_{_\mathrm{\scriptstyle Ph\mathrlap{\mathrm{aseSpace}}}} {\integrando}=1 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you comment these lines of code in your comment?  "\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[Eq#1]{\ensuremath{ \displaystyle#2}}}"   and   "\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}"

Comment: Sorry for the `\eqmathbox` command: as you didn't post a full code, I took a preamble of mine. As to `\dd`,  I use it  for the differential symbol in integrals, to have it in roman with a correct spacing (borrowed from an egreg's code on this site). Remember I asked what  the `\other_expression` command was.

Comment: Ok! Anyway\other_expression was the final part of \integrando. I have just corrected the full definition of \integrando in the upper post.

Comment: The main difference with my code seems to be the order of $p$ and $q$ in the fraction. This being said, for spacing reasons (and save a bit of typing) you should use `\dd` (whatever name you give it).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `\int\limits`, which places the term "PhaseSpace" fully *below*  the integral symbol; the `\rlap` directive allows for right-hand overlap with subsequent material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}

\[
\int\limits_{\rlap{\scriptsize PhaseSpace}}
  \ \rho^{}_{\mu\text{canonico}}\,
  \frac{\mathrm{d}q^{3N}\,\mathrm{d}p^{3N}}{h^{3N}}=1
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: And.. if I used a math expression instead of the text "PhaseSpace" ? The code give error.

Comment: @Alberto - Please tell me which math expression you have in mind for using instead of "PhaseSpace".

Comment: For example $E\leq\mathcal{H}\leq E+\Delta E$

Comment: @Alberto - Just replace `PhaseSpace` with `$E\leq\mathcal{H}\leq E+\Delta E$`.